# Declaration of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

In C++ whats the difference between
`char const *ptr=&ch;`
and
`const char *ptr=&ch;`

Comment: There is no difference, for more information : http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211954/difference-between-these-two-const-pointer-declarations-c

Comment: Additionally, You can use [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

They are the same, i.e. `pointer to const char`.

However `char * const ptr` *is* different, being a `const pointer to (non-const) char`.

And just to complete the set, `const char * const ptr` is a `const pointer to const char`.

Comment: This is a good example for agueing in favor of putting the `const` qualified *after* the type being qualified. `char const *` looks odd to many people but it's consistent with `char const * const`.

Answer (score 7):

No difference in C++.

It is important `const` is before `*` or after `*`.

Answer (score 6):

**Const** applies to whatever is on its immediate left (other than if there is nothing there in which case it applies to whatever is its immediate right). So there is no difference.

`char * const ptr` would be a const pointer to variable value though.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have covered the technical solution - your two examples are the same.

Many people prefer to read from right to left when dealing with `const` in C++. In English, we like to think of a constant X, while C++ likes to parse an X const. Reading right to left yields a more English result.

A rather extreme example:

```
C const * bar(A * const, B const * const) const;
```

From right to left this reads as 'A constant function `bar` taking as parameters a constant pointer to an `A` and a constant pointer to a constant `B`, returning a pointer to a constant `C`'. Note that all three kinds of pointers are different.

Comment: If anyone's interested, the book 'C++ Gotchas' by Stephen C. Dewhurst talks about this technique of declaring pointers.

Answer (score 0):

`char const *ptr=&ch;` and `const char *ptr=&ch;` means char is const, where as the pointer is variable (or it can be changed).

But In case of `char * const ptr`, you cannot re-assign the pointer once you set it. so its a const pointer to a char string.